# is it possible to open voice memos app programmatically

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios8

i need to open voice memos app programmatically just like photo libraries and retrieve prerecorded voice memo.i am trying to find any documentation regarding this feature.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not possible to access pre-recorded voice memos from within your app. Your best bet would be to record and store new voice memos using AVAudioRecorder and save it in your app's sandbox. Below discussion should give you better idea on how to do it:

[Record audio file and save locally on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135687/record-audio-file-and-save-locally-on-iphone)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response . i am already using AVAudioRecorder