# How to record audio and get it as NSData in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio-recording, data-conversion

I want to record some thing in my app and post it to some API.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple tutorial might help you

https://www.appcoda.com/ios-avfoundation-framework-tutorial/

Once you are done recording then you have to choose do you want

```
 AFNetworking or NSURLConnection
```

to send the audio to the server

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this link for recording and saving audio in local iPhone storage (ex: Document Directory).

[Record audio file and save locally on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135687/record-audio-file-and-save-locally-on-iphone)

Once you saved it you can convert file content as NSData

```
NSDate *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:audioFilePath];
// audioFilePath is the path of audio either from document 
// directory or any other location.
```